# android getAuthToken hang after authToken reset

Tags: android, accountmanager

Im having problem on getAuthToken() provided in android AccountManager where  (steps as below):

1. after resetting the authToken to null (in logout process)
2. invalidate the new null authToken
3. set new authToken to new string provided by server (login back)
4. invalidate the new string authToken
5. and try to check/get on the new authToken,

but on getting the new authToken via getAuthToken() method, the call
future.getResult() hangs forever. this doesnt happen on first time login *during account creation. i able to get the auth token using the same callable class.

Below are my defined callable class. please advice on how to solve this matter.

```
private AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = null;
private String authToken;

class GetAuthTokenTask implements Callable<Bundle> {

private AccountManager accountManager;
private Account account;
private String authType;
private Activity activity;

    public GetAuthTokenTask(AccountManager accountManager, Account account, String authType, Activity activity) {
    this.accountManager = accountManager;
    this.account = account;
    this.authType = authType;
    this.activity = activity;
}

/**
 * Computes a result, or throws an exception if unable to do so.
 *
 * @return computed result
 * @throws Exception if unable to compute a result
 */
@Override
public Bundle call() throws Exception {
    return getAuthToken();
}

private Bundle getAuthToken() {
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    future = accountManager.getAuthToken(account, authType, null, activity, null, null);
    try {
        Bundle result = future.getResult();
        if (result!=null) {
            authToken = result.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        }
    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bundle output = new Bundle();
    output.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken );
    return output;
    }
}


//caller method

private String getAuthToken(Account account, String authType) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    GetAuthTokenTask authTokenTask = new GetAuthTokenTask(accountManager, account, authType, (Activity)getBaseContext());
    FutureTask<Bundle> result = new FutureTask<Bundle>(authTokenTask);
    es.execute(result);
    Bundle resultBundle = new Bundle();
    try {
        resultBundle = result.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
}
```

Comment: Try passing in a AccountManagerCallback and getting it from the bundle.
The method getAuthToken in the Authenticator is only ever called when the auth token is null. If there is one set it will simply be returned in the bundle of the callback

Comment: do you mean like this,
`private AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callBack = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

        @Override
        public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
            try {
                authToken = (String)future.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN); // this is your auth token
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }; `

Comment: That looks about right. How did it go.

Comment: it still hang on future.getResult() / arg0.getResult()

Comment: Can you post your code for your authenticator

Comment: this code is triggered manually, not via authenticator, this due to on doing certain process, user token need to validate first, 

If you are looking on how is call the GetAuthTask, i updated the above post with caller method.

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid use of activity like this

```
future = accountManager.getAuthToken(account, authType, null, true, null, null);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.